# perf-report show value of CPU register

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, intel, perf

I follow [this document](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-record.txt) and using `perf record` with `--intr-regs=ax,bx,r15`, trying to log additional CPU register information with PEBS record.

But how do I view those info from perf.data? The original command is `perf report`, and it only shows a few fields such as overhead, command, shared object and symbol.

Is there any way to show CPU regs' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `perf script` data dumping command with the `iregs` field: `perf script -F ip,sym,iregs`. All fields `-F` are documented with source code of [tools/perf/builtin-script.c - `struct output_option .. all_output_options`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/builtin-script.c#L90), and `iregs` is still here (also `OPT_CALLBACK('F', "fields" ...` in same file). There is also perf-script.txt documentation - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-script.txt#L115

> ```
> -F::
> --fields::
>     Comma separated list of fields to print. Options are:
>     comm, tid, pid, time, cpu, event, trace, ip, sym, dso, addr, symoff,
>     srcline, period, iregs, brstack, brstacksym, flags, bpf-output, brstackinsn,
>     callindent, insn, insnlen. Field list can be prepended with the type, trace, sw or hw,
>     to indicate to which event type the field list applies.
> ```

---

There were commits into linux kernel git which mention flag `--intr-regs`. Start from option implementation:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=intr-regs&type=

> `tools/perf/builtin-record.c`
>       OPT_CALLBACK_OPTARG('I', "intr-regs", &record.opts.sample_intr_regs, NULL, "any register",

Then search for 'sample_intr_regs' in commits: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=sample_intr_regs&type=Commits

Several commits were about kernel part and perf_attr debug print. But this has example of `intr-regs` printing (Sep 1, 2015)
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/532026612455a4a6fd27c1b2e7111263f63218a2

> Pull perf/core improvements and fixes from Arnaldo Carvalho de Melo:
>     - Add ability to specify to select which registers to record,
>       to reduce the size of perf.data files, and also allow printing
>       the registers in 'perf script': (Stephane Eranian)
>
> ```
>   # perf record --intr-regs=AX,SP usleep 1
>   [ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
>   [ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.016 MB perf.data (8 samples) ]
>   # perf script -F ip,sym,iregs | tail -5
>    ffffffff8105f42a native_write_msr_safe   AX:0xf    SP:0xffff8802629c3c00
>    ffffffff8105f42a native_write_msr_safe   AX:0xf    SP:0xffff8802629c3c00
>    ffffffff81761ac0 _raw_spin_lock   AX:0xffff8801bfcf8020    SP:0xffff8802629c3ce8
>    ffffffff81202bf8 __vma_adjust_trans_huge   AX:0x7ffc75200000    SP:0xffff8802629c3b30
>    ffffffff8122b089 dput   AX:0x101    SP:0xffff8802629c3c78
>   #
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to achieve it by using `perf report -D`, and then find the registers' name which you need for record by record (but this seems to be very inefficient..).

Or someone else can provide a more streamlined approach?

Comment: There is also `perf script` to print perf.data file for program postprocessing (and it also supports "`-D`" full dump option. The doc of perf mem is perf-mem.txt, not perf-record.txt: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-mem.txt, and this is to be used with `perf mem report`, not with `perf report`: ""perf mem report" displays the result. It invokes perf report with the right set of options  to display a memory access profile."

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a typo. I actually want to use `perf record` not `perf mem record`, and I already fixed my question :)